# $wpdb->insert not working inside save_post tag

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, database

Will someone help me in this.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'product_price_box_save' );
function product_price_box_save( $post_id ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return;

    global $wpdb;

    if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['store_details_box_content_nonce'], 'store_details_box_content' ) ) {

        if (is_int($_POST['store_pincode'])) {
            # code...
            $store_pincode = htmlentities(trim($_POST['store_pincode']));
        }
        $wpdb->insert('cs_shop_details', array(
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'shop_pincode' => $store_pincode,
        ), array("%d", "%d"));
        $wpdb->show_errors();
  }

}
```

Does anyone have idea why the data isn't entered to database even the code looks good. Am I missing something or doing it wrong.
What I want to achieve is that when user publishes or updates the post the data should be saved to custom made database table.
Thanks.

Comment: First of all - you should use $post_id and not get_the_ID in this context. And even more important - what is $wpdb->shop_details - there is no such field in WPDB class

Comment: did that but still not working

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: no error, neither success. don't know why this isn't happening

Comment: Check SQL errors - there has to be one if that insert doesn’t work.

Comment: no sql errors showing. is there any function or something else which can help in this